# Start perl script with Win32::Process::Create

Tags: perl, winapi, module

I would like to translate all of the system commands in my script to Win::32::Process::Create commands. CPAN tells me the syntax:

```
Win32::Process::Create($obj,$appname,$cmdline,$iflags,$cflags,$curdir)
```

So, I tried to apply it:

```
Win32::Process::Create( $Win32processObj,
                        "C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe",
                        "'C:\\Users\\script.pl','$arg'",
                         0,
                         NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                         "." ) ||  die "Failed to create process.\n";
```

When I run this, I don't get an error, but I don't start a new process either...

When I use GetProcessID(), I get a pid, but it doesn't correspond to anything in the tasklist... (I'm assuming the created process ends before I can see it displayed in the tasklist).

Comment: Yeah and `"perl C:\\Users\\script.pl $arg";`

Comment: The important parameter to get right is `$cmdline`. This is a single string that looks just like it does when you enter it on the command line (so no commas and extraneous quotes). `Win32::Process::Create` has a return value. Check it, and check `Win32::Process::ErrorReport()` and `$^E` and `$!`.

Comment: You might also be interested in the `system 1, @cmd` syntax for Windows. See [`perlport`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport#system)

Comment: I used     `sub ErrorReport{
        print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
    }` and got nothing. `Win32::Process::Create` returns 1. It's possible I am not checking them correctly. When I try to print `$^E` and `$!`, I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, Windows says it created the process. Accoding to your question, you even have its process id of the process you claim never got created. I'm gonna go out on a limb and say you are mistaken.

You should now check what code the process ended with. `perl -E'say $!=THECODE;'` might give you a hint. But chances are it's because you tell Perl to execute a file named `'C:\Users\script.pl'` (as opposed to `C:\Users\script.pl`).

Comment: Now `$^E = "There are no more files"`..When I type `perl -E'say $!=THECODE;` into the command line, I get `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`. I also tried to run it as `C:\Users\script.pl` to no avail.

Comment: 1) You said CreateProcess returns true, so printing `$^E` is useless. There's no error message unless there's an error.

Comment: 2) `$^E` does not give the exit code of a process; `$Win32processObj->GetExitCode()` does.

Comment: 3) That's because there's a quote missing in my command. Fixed.

Comment: `use Win32::Process;
    $avar = Win32::Process::Create(
        $Process
        , 
        "C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe"
        ,
        "perl C:/Users/script.pl $arg"
        ,
        0
        ,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
        ,
        "."
        ) || die ErrorReport();` Worked! Thanks